# How can i remove part of code from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, monkeypatching

I use gem `money` it works ok on my localmachine but when i try to deploy in on my production server i have got an error `Could not find sixarm_ruby_unaccent-1.1.1` its dependency for `money` gem

I have tried to install it manually on my production server but got the same error.

So i have decided to remove this part of code from gem.

But how to do it properly?

Simply remove this code from gem or what should i do?

lib/Money.rb

```
require "bigdecimal"
require "bigdecimal/util"
require "set"
require "i18n"
require "sixarm_ruby_unaccent"
require "money/currency"
require "money/money"

# Overwrites unaccent method of sixarm_ruby_unaccent.
class String
  def unaccent
    accentmap = ACCENTMAP
    accentmap.delete("\u{0142}") # Delete ł symbol from ACCENTMAP used in PLN currency
    accentmap.delete("\u{010D}") # Delete č symbol from ACCENTMAP used in CZK currency
    accentmap.delete("\u{FDFC}") # Delete ﷼ symbol from ACCENTMAP used in IRR, SAR and YER currencies
    accentmap.delete("\u{20A8}") # Delete ₨ symbol from ACCENTMAP used in INR, LKR, MUR, NPR, PKR and SCR currencies
    split(//u).map {|c| accentmap[c] || c }.join("")
  end
end
```

i need to remove `require "sixarm_ruby_unaccent"` and `unaccent`method

Comment: I think that is the wrong approach, unless you're willing to re-write and then monkey patch part of the gem. You should investigate why the problem is happening in your server instead of changing the way a gem works because you can't install it.

Comment: @lcguida. ok how can i monkeypatch gem?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to advise you to not to. You need to understand the gem in order to do it, and make sure that won't break other things, and to know that any future changes in the gem may not be compatible with the code you're changing.

Comment: Especially knowing that `sixarm_ruby_unaccent` is written in pure Ruby, it sounds most logical to install it.

Comment: @MladenJablanović  i have added it to my gemfile also i have installed it to production server

Comment: I am pretty sure the creator of the `money` gem added `sixarm_ruby_unaccent` for a reason. You cannot just remove a dependency and expect the gem to work correctly without. You would need to fork the `money` gem and rewrite everything that is depending on `sixarm_ruby_unaccent`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess removing that line might introduce another bug to your application. I'd be curious to learn what it does first. However, have you tried to delete your `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` again? In case you want to go on however, it may be best to `gem 'money', require: false` then either in initializer, or in your lib/money.rb

```
require "bigdecimal"
require "bigdecimal/util"
require "set"
require "i18n"
require "money/currency"
require "money/money"
```

Add the lib dir to your autoload_path and you should be good to go.
However, I think a better approach is to look for what's causing the error in the first place, rather than introduce this bug to your application